# How do I change the dimensions of images according to if they are landscape or portraits?

Tags: css

I am very new to css. I have a flow of pictures which I preload in js to determine if they are portraits or landscapes. Then I want to return a div according to that. My css looks like that

```
.image-wrapper-landscape {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
margin: 5px 0;
&:hover {
  .text-wrapper {
    opacity: 1;
  }
 }
}

.image-wrapper-portrait {
width : 49.5%;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
margin: 5px 0;
&:hover {
  .text-wrapper {
    opacity: 1;
  }
 }
}
```

Then my divs are

```
<div
      className='image-wrapper-portrait'
      key={i}
    >
      <img src={image.src} alt={altText} data-position={image.position} />
 </div>


  <div
      className='image-wrapper-landscape'
      key={i}
    >
      <img src={image.src} alt={altText} data-position={image.position} />
 </div>
```

This doesn't seem to work though since the portrait pictures all look different. What I would like to do is resize all of them so that I end up with a flow of either landscapes or portraits, I also tried pixels instead of percentages but still nothing. I would appreciate nay help, css confuses me.

Comment: Your CSS wont get applied, use `class=""` instead of `className=""` and I suppose you want `id=""` instead of `key=""`. Also don't foreget to encase your values with `""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's working for you, try making the `img` width 100%;
But while using scss try to make it useful.

.scss

```
.image-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px 0;
  &.portrait {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  &.landscape {
    width : 49.5%;
  }
  &:hover {
    .text-wrapper {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

use class name `image-wrapper portrait` for portrait and use `image-wrapper landscape`.

And use `object-fit` if you wants to.